# JNDI lookup only returns "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException"

Tags: gwt, jboss, jndi

I'm trying to implement an ejb-call by using JNDI-naming.

Setup:

- JBoss-6.1.0.Final
- ear-deploy:

  - gwt.war
  - ejb.jar

My problem is, although the JNDIView shows me the existing ejb, I'm not able to reach it.

In my RemoteServiceServlet I try to reach the ejb, which is deployed in the ejb.jar inside the same ear-package.

I allready tried several calls, as I wasn't sure about the correct jndi code.

```
try 
{
    productLocal = (ProductLocal) context.lookup("ProductHome/local");
} 
catch (NamingException e) 
{
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

also tried:

```
productLocal = (ProductLocal) context.lookup("ProductLocal");
productLocal = (ProductLocal) context.lookup("sung_app_kylintv/ProductHome/local");
```

The **stateless ejb** is assigned like this:

```
@Stateless
@Local(ProductLocal.class)
@Remote(ProductRemote.class)
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding="ProductLocal")
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="ProductRemote")
public class ProductHome extends HomeBase<ProductEntity> implements SessionBean, Serializable, ProductLocal
```

The **context initiation**:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
p.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
p.put("java.naming.provider.url","jnp://localhost:1099");

context = new InitialContext(p);
```

My **JNDIView**:

```
  +- sung_app_kylintv (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   +- CategoryHome (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.CategoryLocal)
  |   |   +- local-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.CategoryLocal (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.CategoryLocal)
  |   |   +- remote-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.CategoryRemote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.CategoryRemote)
  |   |   +- remote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.CategoryRemote)
  |   +- ProductHome (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.ProductLocal)
  |   |   +- remote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.ProductRemote)
  |   |   +- remote-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.ProductRemote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.ProductRemote)
  |   |   +- local-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.ProductLocal (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.ProductLocal)
  |   +- CustomerHome (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local-sung.common.behavior.FindAllBehaviour (class: Proxy for: sung.common.behavior.FindAllBehaviour)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.common.behavior.FindAllBehaviour)
  |   +- Option (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.OptionLocal (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.OptionLocal)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.OptionLocal)
  |   |   +- remote-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.OptionRemote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.OptionRemote)
  |   |   +- remote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.OptionRemote)
  |   +- DurationHome (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.DurationLocal)
  |   |   +- local-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.DurationLocal (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.DurationLocal)
  |   |   +- remote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.DurationRemote)
  |   |   +- remote-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.DurationRemote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.DurationRemote)
  |   +- VariantHome (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.VariantLocal)
  |   |   +- local-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.VariantLocal (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.VariantLocal)
  |   |   +- remote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.VariantRemote)
  |   |   +- remote-sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.VariantRemote (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.product.VariantRemote)
  |   +- VelocityBean (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejb.velocity.Velocity)
  |   |   +- local-sung.app.kylintv.ejb.velocity.Velocity (class: Proxy for: sung.app.kylintv.ejb.velocity.Velocity)
  |   +- CustomerAddressHome (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- local-sung.common.behavior.FindAllBehaviour (class: Proxy for: sung.common.behavior.FindAllBehaviour)
  |   |   +- local (class: Proxy for: sung.common.behavior.FindAllBehaviour)
  |   +- OrderEntityHome (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- no-interface (class: sung.app.kylintv.ejbclient.order.OrderEntityHome_$$_javassist_50)
```

Are there any requirements for jndi to work properly in a case like this?

Comment: `java:comp/env/ProductHome/local`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using

```
productLocal = (ProductLocal) context.lookup("sung_app_kylintv/ProductHome/local")
```

returned a slightly different error message:

```
2011-11-24 12:37:07,893 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) productLocal called successfully.
2011-11-24 12:37:07,893 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) productLocal calling createTestEntry().
2011-11-24 12:37:07,950 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) org.jboss.injection.manager.spi.InjectionException: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: sung not bound]
```

After a colleague of mine took a look  the error has been identified: I tried an Injection using **@EJB inside of that class ProductHome, that used mappedName="sung/..."**. The mappedName isn't correct and even not required at all, inside the ejb-project the connections do allready exist and work. Hope, this may help others as well.

**Solution:**
I had to fix my ProductHome by removing the mappedName-Attribute on my ejb-call. After that the class can be instanciated and functions are called.